# Setting object transpareny in Navisworks

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-navisworks

We are facing a problem when trying to modify object transparencies via API.

Please see our code below.

The issue we are having, is in a certain model, objects are set to 100% transparency, even though in the code we are setting 50%. It is only affecting certain objects in the model.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

```
using Autodesk.Navisworks.Api;
using Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Plugins;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using Application = Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Application;

namespace NavisworksTransparencyModifier
{
    [PluginAttribute("Trasnparency",                   //Plugin name
                    "ADSK",                                       //4 character Developer ID or GUID
                    ToolTip = "Transparency modifier",//The tooltip for the item in the ribbon
                    DisplayName = "Transparency modifier plugin")]
    public class TransparencyModifier : AddInPlugin
    {

        public override int Execute(params string[] parameters)
        {
            Document doc = Application.ActiveDocument;

            List<ModelItem> list = doc.CurrentSelection.SelectedItems.ToList();
            if (list != null)
            {
                //Application.ActiveDocument.Models.ResetAllPermanentMaterials();
                Application.ActiveDocument.Models.OverridePermanentTransparency(list,50);


            }
            else
            {
                // Handle case when no object is selected
                Console.WriteLine("Please select an object first.");
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the value is between 0 and 1.
If you wish to set the transparency to 50%, please use 0.5.